# Unable to display the first column

Tags: c++

Hello I just get some data from a file but it is very weird becuase I can't get the first column of the text file. This is my text file :

```
1.2 2.6 3.5
1.02 3.05 4.65
7.15 0.54 9.26
```

Here is my code :

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>

int main() {
  std::ifstream myFile("a.txt");
  std::string line;

  while(std::getline(myFile, line)) {
    std::string col1, col2, col3;
    myFile >> col1, col2 >> col3;
    std::cout << col1 << " " << col2 << " " << col3 << std::endl;
  }

  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

So I don't understand why I can't see in the terminal when I execute the program :

```
1.2 2.6 3.5
1.02 3.05 4.65
7.15 0.54 9.26
```

Instead I see this :

```
1.02 3.05 4.65
7.15 0.54 9.26
```

Thank you a lot !

Comment: you have a comma which is probably the problem `col1, col2` which needs to be change to `col1 >> col2`

Comment: You first `getline()` from the file and ignore the line, then continue reading into your other variables.  If you don't want your first line to disappear into your `line` variable, don't call `getline()`?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend using `operator>>` to input your data:

```
double col1, col2, col3;
char comma;
while (myFile >> col1)
{
  myFile >> comma;
  myFile >> col2 >> comma;
  myFile >> col3;
  //...
}
```

A better approach would be to model the input line with a structure:

```
struct Record
{
  double value1;
  double value2;
  double value3;
  friend std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r);
};

std::istream& operator>>(std::istream& input, Record& r)
{
  char comma;
  input >> r.value1 >> comma;
  input >> r.value2 >> comma;
  input >> r.value3;
  return input;
}
```

The above code allows you to read in a file like this:

```
std::vector<Record> database;
Record r;
while (myFile >> r)
{
  database.push_back(r);
}
```

The code fragment to read in the file doesn't depend on the format of the data and can be used to read in other formats.  The structure `Record` determines how the data is input.

Answer (score 0):

**Getline() and >>**

The problem is you use `getline()` to check your input and try do read from your stream using `>>` afterwards. This does not work as intended.

Imagine it some kind of cursor in your stream. There are member functions of `std::fstream` that move this cursor, others don't.

You move this cursor forward by using `getline()`. When you use `>>` the cursor has already passed the position you want to get.

There are some workarounds for this. The most easy one is

```
int main(){
    std::ifstream myFile("a.txt");
    std::string line;
    std::string col1, col2, col3;
    while(myFile >> col1 >> col2 >> col3){
        std::cout << col1 << " " << col2 << " " << col3 << std::endl;
    }
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

another one using stringstreams is

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

int main(){
    std::ifstream myFile("a.txt");
    std::string line;
    while(std::getline(myFile, line)){
        std::string col1, col2, col3;
        std::istringstream stream(line);
        copy(std::istream_iterator<std::string>(stream),
        std::istream_iterator<std::string>(),
        std::ostream_iterator<std::string>(std::cout, " "));
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

**Bad use of comma operator**

The following line could also cause problems

```
myFile >> col1, col2 >> col3;
```

My compiler `Apple LLVM version 8.1.0 (clang-802.0.38)` doesn't even allow this. (Reproduced [here](https://ideone.com/2eWd8l)) So I suppose you want to use the comma operator `,` like this

```
 myFile >> (col1, col2) >> col3;
```

The comma operator does the following: If you got `expression1,expression2` `expression1` get evaluated, then `expression2` gets evaluated and the result of `expression2` is returned as the result of the whole expression `expression1,expression2`.

Let's check how `>>` and `,` work together. [Here](http://de.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operator_precedence) you can see that `>>` binds stronger than `,` (actually `,` has the weakest precedence of all C++ operators).

That means

```
myFile >> (col1, col2) >> col3;
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^
          result is col2
```

has the same effect as

```
myFile >> col2 >> col3;
```

and `col1` is therefore unused. My compiler (using `-Wall -Wpedantic`) gives the warning

> expression result unused [-Wunused-value]